# How to set a limit on how many times my android button can be clicked

Tags: android, android-button

I am looking to get my Android button to be clickable only 15 times. Heres what ive tried so far.Does anyone have any ideas.

// RedButton

```
    counter= 15;
    redAdd1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redButton);
    player1 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.player1Button);
    player2 = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.player2Button);
    player1ScoreDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player1Score);
    player2ScoreDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.player2Score);
    counterDisplay= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.count);


    redAdd1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (player1.isChecked()) {
            counter -= 1;
            counterDisplay.setText("" + counter);

        if (player2.isChecked()) {
            counter -= 1;
            counterDisplay.setText("" + counter);

        }
        if (counter == 0); {
            redAdd1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I see no other way to do it then what you are basically already doing

Comment: If both toggle buttons are selected, that will decrement 2 on each click and probably will go from 1 to -1 (bypassing the `counter==0` if sttm). Is this scenario possible?

Comment: check counter is reducing or not.. this should work.. this one worked for me.. int counter = 0;
   public void Clicked()
   {
    
    counter= counter+1;
    if(counter == 15){
     
     Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     btn.setEnabled(false);
    }
    
   }

Comment: I've fixed the problem now. The solution was that little semi colon after  (counter ==0) in the IF statement. I deleted it and it worked fine. Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not familiar with what you exactly want, let's start from scratch, and you can modify it as you'd like:

```
Integer maxclicks = 5; Integer currentnumber = 0;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (currentnumber == maxclicks); {
               button.setEnabled(false);
           } else {
               currentnumber = currentnumber + 1;
           }
        } });
```

As you can see, we keep it simple, and separate the current and the max click variables.

Answer (score 0):

this is more better when it is reusable. just wrap your onclicklisteners for views around the following decorated class:

```
public class OnClickRateLimitedDecoratedListener implements View.OnClickListener {

private final static int CLICK_DELAY_DEFAULT = 300;
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
private int mClickDelay;


public OnClickRateLimitedDecoratedListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this(onClickListener, CLICK_DELAY_DEFAULT);
}

//customize your own delay
public OnClickRateLimitedDecoratedListener(View.OnClickListener onClickListener, int delay) {
    this.onClickListener = onClickListener;
    mClickDelay = delay;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    v.setClickable(false);
    onClickListener.onClick(v);

    v.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            v.setClickable(true);
        }
    }, mClickDelay);
}
```

}